# Where to set-up the toolbar in a fragment? onCreate() or onStart()?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-lifecycle

I'm writing an app that involves several activities: each of them is composed by more fragments. In almost each fragment I want to **set-up a different toolbar**... where should I do that? I used to do almost everything inside the `onCreate()` or the `onCreateView()`, but now I'm asking myself: *maybe it's more correct to put it in the `onStart()`?* 
I know how activity and fragment lifecycles work... but I didn't find an answer to **my specific case**.
Here's the code I used in one of the fragments:

```
// Toolbar setup
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
ActionBar actionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
if (actionBar != null)
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    Toolbar tb = (Toolbar) activity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main);
    tb.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FragmentManager mng = getFragmentManager();
            mng.popBackStack();
        }
    }); 
if (activity.getSupportActionBar() != null)
    activity.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.toolbar_title);
    tb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Here's a part of the `activity_main.xml` file where `R.id.toolbar_main` is defined:

```
<!--- [...] --->
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<!--- [...] --->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it in .onCreate() method - see Google's sample project for Material design: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Even the particular changes for each fragment would better go in the `onCreate()` of the relative fragment? In the sample project you linked I see no change of the toolbar in fragments, only in the activity.

Comment: Well, Toolbar is just another View in layout, is is supposed to be customized alog with another views.

Answer (score 1):

include toolbar in your activity and change in color, title etc in your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Well I will suggest to put Toolbar at you Activity class. You can create custom toolbar as well as per your need. During calling fragment you can make changes (color,theme etc) at your activity or at your fragment by calling method.

Comment: My question is about `onCreate()` and `onStart()` methods mainly! Where to put those changes in the fragment you talk about? Is there any substantial difference?